# Symmetric difference involving three sets: $A\triangle B\triangle C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I learned that the symmetric difference of sets $A, B$ is given by:
$$A\triangle B=(A-B)\cup (B-A).$$

But I encountered the following expression: $A\triangle B\triangle C$, and I don’t understand what it means.

How do I apply the definition of symmetric difference when three sets are involved?

In fact I am stuck on a question

There are three set $A,B,C$.

How can I find the expression that the elements in two of these sets but are not in all three sets?

My answer is $A \cup B \cup C -[(A-B\cup C)\cup (B-A\cup C)\cup (C-A\cup B)+A\cap B\cap C]$

But the answer is $A\cup B \cup (C-A)\triangle B \triangle C$
seems more simple than mine, how to get that answer?

Comment: It means $A\Delta(B\Delta C)$, so it is $(A-(B\Delta C))\cup ((B\Delta C)-A)$.

Answer (score 0):

Color a venn diagram. Count how many of $A$, $B$ and $C$ that any element of $(A\Delta B)\Delta C$ belong to.  You will quickly see this operation is associative and  be able to see what $A_1\Delta A_2 \cdots A_n$ is.